# Quickest way to generate the waveform of MP3 (server side solution)?

Tags: mp3, soundcloud, waveform

I try to generate the waveform image of a MP3 file the quickest way.

All solutions I found decode the Mp3 file entirely and after generates the waveform. I think this is a waste of time, because only frequencies decoding is needed.

To summarize , I would like an algorithm working like "Mp3 direct cut" software, and not like audacity... (I think soundcoud work this way)
OK, this is not the same waveform wich is generated in the 2 cases, but the fastest solution is the best for me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why don't you use the waveform provided by SoundCloud?

Comment: Because mp3 files are not hosted at soundcloud. They are and must stays on my server. I'm looking for an autonomous solution.

Comment: Oh sorry, thought you're using SoundCloud because you tagged it.

Comment: http://waveformjs.org/